# Stored Procedure using Group by and Order by

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have this in my stored proc. I would like to Group the records by `Offer_Continent` and Order by `Offer_CountryCode ASC` but it doesn't bring the results in the Grouped by continent order.

Below is my select statement

```
    SELECT
        Offer_SubCatName,
        Offer_TagLine,
        Offer_Type,         
        CustomOffersAttributes.Attribute_Value3,
        Offer_ID,
        Offer_ShortDescription,
        Offer_AccommRating,
        Offer_ResortName,
        Offer_AccommName,
        Offer_CountryCode,
        Offer_Continent,
        Offer_FlightSupplierCode,
        Offer_OriginAirport,
        Offer_DestinationAirport,
        CustomOffersAttributes.Attribute_Value4,
        CustomOffersAttributes.Attribute_Value,
        CustomOffersAttributes.Attribute_Value2,
        Op_Name                     
    FROM
        CustomOffers
        INNER JOIN CustomOffersAttributes ON CustomOffersAttributes.Attribute_ID = dbo.fn_CustomOffers_CheapestDatePrice(CustomOffers.Offer_ID)
        FULL OUTER JOIN Suppliers ON Suppliers.Op_Code = CustomOffers.Offer_FlightSupplierCode
    WHERE
        (
            @CategoryID = 0
        OR
            Offer_CatID = @CategoryID
        )
        AND
        (
            @OfferIDs = ''
            OR
            Offer_ID in (select val from fn_CreateInList(@OfferIDs))
        )
        AND
        (
            @SubCategoryName = ''
        OR
            Offer_SubCatName = @SubCategoryName
        )
        AND ISNULL(Offer_Starts,GETDATE()) <= GETDATE()
        AND ISNULL(Offer_Expires,GETDATE()) >= GETDATE()

    GROUP BY
        Offer_Continent,
        Offer_SubCatName,
        Offer_TagLine,
        Offer_Type,         
        CustomOffersAttributes.Attribute_Value3,            
        Offer_ID,
        Offer_ShortDescription,
        Offer_AccommRating,
        Offer_ResortName,
        Offer_AccommName,
        Offer_CountryCode,
        Offer_Continent,
        Offer_FlightSupplierCode,
        Offer_OriginAirport,
        Offer_DestinationAirport,
        CustomOffersAttributes.Attribute_Value4,
        CustomOffersAttributes.Attribute_Value,
        CustomOffersAttributes.Attribute_Value2,
        Op_Name 
    ORDER BY 
         Offer_Continent ASC, 
         Offer_CountryCode ASC
```

The above gets me the result as below

Africa (Offer_Continent)

- Kenya - (Offer_CountrCode)

Caribbean(Offer_Continent)

- Antigua - (Offer_CountrCode)
- Barbados - (Offer_CountrCode)
- Grenada - (Offer_CountrCode)
- Montego Bay - (Offer_CountrCode)
- Kingston - (Offer_CountrCode)
- St Lucia - (Offer_CountrCode)
- Tobago - (Offer_CountrCode)

But what I would like to have is a ONLY order by `Offer_CountryCode`
However, when I just order by `Offer_CountryCode` it looks like below

Caribbean(Offer_Continent)

- Antigua - (Offer_CountrCode)
- Barbados - (Offer_CountrCode)
- Grenada - (Offer_CountrCode)
- Montego Bay - (Offer_CountrCode)
- Kingston - (Offer_CountrCode)

Afirca (Offer_Continent)

- Kenya - (Offer_CountrCode)

Caribbean(Offer_Continent)

- St Lucia - (Offer_CountrCode)
- Tobago - (Offer_CountrCode)

As you can see caribbean is repeated. This is why I thought to use GROUP BY Clause.Anyway what I would like to have is a recors set that looks like below.

Caribbean(Offer_Continent)

- Antigua - (Offer_CountrCode)
- Barbados - (Offer_CountrCode)
- Grenada - (Offer_CountrCode)
- Montego Bay - (Offer_CountrCode)
- Kingston - (Offer_CountrCode)
- St Lucia - (Offer_CountrCode)
- Tobago - (Offer_CountrCode)

Africa (Offer_Continent)

- Kenya - (Offer_CountrCode)

Hope it's clear what I'm trying to do..? Thanks in advance..

Comment: It looks about right (other than Offer_Continent appearing twice in your `GROUP BY`). Can you provide an example of the type of results your getting, and what you expected?

Comment: Okay, that's good - we can see two ways you *don't* want it ordered (apparently), but its still unclear from your description how you *would* like it ordered.

Comment: Hi I would like it to order by Offer_CountryCode but not by Continents. So the results would look like "Caribbean" and uder that you'd have ASC ordered results for caribbean and then "Africa" and ASC ordered list of countries under there.. and I would like carribean to come first nort africa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so you want to order by continents and then countries, but the order of the continents should be determined by the earliest country within each continent.

I think the following will work:

```
;WITH Offers AS (
SELECT
    Offer_SubCatName,
    Offer_TagLine,
    Offer_Type,         
    CustomOffersAttributes.Attribute_Value3,
    Offer_ID,
    Offer_ShortDescription,
    Offer_AccommRating,
    Offer_ResortName,
    Offer_AccommName,
    Offer_CountryCode,
    Offer_Continent,
    Offer_FlightSupplierCode,
    Offer_OriginAirport,
    Offer_DestinationAirport,
    CustomOffersAttributes.Attribute_Value4,
    CustomOffersAttributes.Attribute_Value,
    CustomOffersAttributes.Attribute_Value2,
    Op_Name                     
FROM
    CustomOffers
    INNER JOIN CustomOffersAttributes ON CustomOffersAttributes.Attribute_ID = dbo.fn_CustomOffers_CheapestDatePrice(CustomOffers.Offer_ID)
    FULL OUTER JOIN Suppliers ON Suppliers.Op_Code = CustomOffers.Offer_FlightSupplierCode
WHERE
    (
        @CategoryID = 0
    OR
        Offer_CatID = @CategoryID
    )
    AND
    (
        @OfferIDs = ''
        OR
        Offer_ID in (select val from fn_CreateInList(@OfferIDs))
    )
    AND
    (
        @SubCategoryName = ''
    OR
        Offer_SubCatName = @SubCategoryName
    )
    AND ISNULL(Offer_Starts,GETDATE()) <= GETDATE()
    AND ISNULL(Offer_Expires,GETDATE()) >= GETDATE()
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Offers o1
ORDER BY
    (SELECT MIN(Offer_Country) from Offers o2 where o2.Offer_Continent = o1.Offer_Continent) asc,
    Offer_Country
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use group by, since you aren't using any aggregate functions.  You can put any fields you want to use to order the data into the `order by` and just not use `group by`.